# wordpress: how to enable the edit and delete action button in wp_list_table class of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Hi i am writing a plugin in which i have displayed various entries from database by extending wordpress wp_list_table class.
To display some action links in every single row i have used this function in such following way.

```
function column_name($item) {
    $actions = array(
        'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s& hotel=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['id']),
        'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&hotel=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['id']),
    );
    return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $item['Name'], $this->row_actions($actions) );
}
```

but from admin page when i click on those links nothing happen only the url changes i searched every ware and most of the examples are using static data in the form of array so what i want to say is how i can make it active by $_GET[] method or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: I think i need to do something like this   

    $testListTable = new Zenith_hotel_Table();
        if ('delete' === $testListTable->current_action()) {
            $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN($ids)");   
        }
    $testListTable->prepare_items();
    $testListTable->display();

 but still how i will get the id of the row to delete of edit

Comment: See this tutorial which handles the delete : http://mac-blog.org.ua/942/ Not sure about the edit action.

Comment: thanks emeraldjava tutorial works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in your settings page, you should add an if statement for the $*GET value. (i.e. the callback from your add*(sub)menu_page call.

e.g.

```
if( isset( $_GET['edit-hotel'] ) ) :
  // Show my edit hotel form
else :
  // Show my WP_List_Table
endif;
```

You can of course show the list table above your edit form as well if appropriate - this is just an example.

Be aware that the WP_List_table class is marked @access private so shouldn't really be used as part of the API. [See this comment from WordPress core developer Andrew Nacin](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/#comment-9617).